Excel: Sumproduct with date range
I'm looking to do a sumproduct with a date range and I am very new to using arrays. My formula regularly has 115 rows and 30 columns, but I reduced it below for troubleshooting:
=SUMPRODUCT(('History'!$G$3:$I$4)*('History'!$C$3:$C$4='Calculator'!C8)*('History'!G1:I1="Order")*('History'!G2:I2&">="&'Calculator'!H2)*('History'!G2:I2&"<="&'Calculator'!H4))
The first section works fine but when I get to ('History'!G2:I2&">="&'Calculator'!H2)*('History'!G2:I2&"<="&'Calculator'!H4)) I get #Value! in the evaluate formula window.
H2 & H4 are dates that find specific dates from the History page based on a couple of other requirements. I have double checked that all sections that involve dates are formatted correctly.
I tested a Sumifs with just the dates to see if it was the dates but I get the correct value I am looking for. Sumifs('History'!G3:I3,'History'!G1:I1,"Order", 'History'!G2:I2,">="&'Calculator'!H2,'History'!G2:I2,"<="&'Calculator'!H4) = 1
Please let me know if further information is needed. Thanks :)

remove the "  and & from around the inequalities  they are not needed with SUMPRODUCT

It should be simple to reproduce your problem if you edit your question to provide a representative data sample as text which can be copy/pasted (not as a screenshot).

Thank you Scott! Your solution worked.

I think you're getting mixed between SUMIFS and SUMPRODUCT. With SUMIFS you need to quote the <= like "<=" but that's not the case for SUMPRODUCT.
Is the reason that you're using SUMPRODUCT rather than SUMIFS because you want to filter both on rows and columns?
Fix:
=SUMPRODUCT(('History'!$G$3:$I$4)*('History'!$C$3:$C$4='Calculator'!C8)*('History'!G1:I1="Order")*('History'!G2:I2>='Calculator'!H2)*('History'!G2:I2<='Calculator'!H4))
Better:
=SUMPRODUCT('History'!$G$3:$I$4,('History'!$C$3:$C$4='Calculator'!$C$8)*('History'!$G$1:$I$1="Order")*('History'!G2:I2>='Calculator'!H2)*('History'!G2:$I$2<='Calculator'!$H$4)
I did a quick mockup to try and visualise what is going on:

